# 3D PGFPlots: show only "visible" part axis

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, 3d

I've this plot where the vertical axis is hidden by the curve. Adding the `axis on top` option leads, of course, to have the axis on the figure.
Is it possible to show only the visible segment of the axis?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
    [view={-20}{20},xlabel=$\theta$,axis equal,axis lines=center,enlargelimits,ticks=none,width=.45\textwidth]
        \addplot3
        [domain=0:360,y domain=0:180, variable=\u, variable y=\v,samples=40,z buffer=sort,surf,colormap/cool]
        ({(sin(u)^2*sin(u)*cos(v)}, {sin(u)^2*sin(u)*sin(v)}, {sin(u)^2*cos(u)});
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image: axis on top]

Comment: Welcome! Please edit your question and complete your code so that it can be compiled.

Comment: It is always worth testing to make sure you've not forgotten anything ;). I've added `\begin{document}` as I'm pretty sure people will get an error without it :-).

Answer (score 4):

Pgfplots currently supports hidden line removal inside of one `\addplot` only. As a consequence, there is no way to let it automatically determine the visible part in your example.

You may be interested in workarounds for the problem. One would be to use `axis lines` which do not intersect the plot as such, i.e. which are either in front of or behind of the figure. In this case, one needs tick and/or grid lines such that one can easily see the view angle:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
    [view={-20}{20},xlabel=$\theta$,axis equal,axis lines=left,enlargelimits,grid=major,width=.45\textwidth]
        \addplot3
        [domain=0:360,y domain=0:180, variable=\u, variable y=\v,samples=40,z buffer=sort,surf,colormap/cool]
        ({(sin(u)^2*sin(u)*cos(v)}, {sin(u)^2*sin(u)*sin(v)}, {sin(u)^2*cos(u)});
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but unfortunately this solution does not fit my goal. That plot must be placed beside the sectional view of the same surface, as shown in this [example](https://i.imgsafe.org/187be69867.png). At the moment I manually drawn, as workaround, a vertical arrow replacing the axis, but I hoped for a more automated solution.

Answer (score 3):

I think the `tikz-3dplot` package could be useful for you.

I'm not an expert, hence my answer is not completely correct (for example, you have to put your function instead of `sin(\tdplottheta)^2`) but I post it because someone else may improve it or it may help you in some way.

However see the [package documentation](http://tug.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/tikz-3dplot/tikz-3dplot_documentation.pdf) for more information.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}

\begin{document}

    \tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{330}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[line join=bevel,tdplot_main_coords, fill]
        \tdplotsphericalsurfaceplot[parametricfill]{36}{48}%
        {sin(\tdplottheta)^2}% you have to put the correct function here
        {black}{-\tdplotr}%
        {\draw[color=black,thick,->] (-2,0,0) -- (2,0,0) node[anchor=north east]{$\theta$};}%
        {\draw[color=black,thick,->] (0,-2,0) -- (0,2,0);}%
        {\draw[color=black,thick,->] (0,0,-1) -- (0,0,1);}%
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]